# Internal style sheet being over riden by external css declared earlier in html doc

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, styles

Im playing around with the front end of a site using the new bootstrap 3.0 and im fine tuning things by irritating in firebug, but there is something odd that i keep noticing

even though my `<head>` is layed out like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">

<style>
 td {padding:0px;}
<style>
```

With the external css being declared before the internal (which im only using during development) the external styles are still over riding them.

To get the `padding:0px;` to work i need to set it as `padding:0px !important;`

Any ideas why this is.. i thought that the last declared peice of css would always override conflicting previously declared css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS precedence is about `!important`, origin (user vs browser), specificity and then order. [Here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/css-101-handling-multiple-rules-for-the-same-element/) is a good explanation.